# Prevent Visual studio from popping on top of other windows when a breakpoint is hit

Tags: visual-studio

Im trying to observe some graphs on my screen in the application, but visual studio keeps jumping on top of other windows when it hits a breakpoint, which makes it impossible. And I can't make the window small enough to debug my code.

Is there a way to keep visual studio minimized when a breakpoint is triggered?

This is for visual studio 2019 on windows 11

Comment: Hi, does Visual Studio 2019 contain the setting options I mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Although I do not have Visual Studio 2019 on my computer, there is an option in Visual Studio 2022 that will not return to the Visual Studio interface when a breakpoint is encountered during debugging. This can be achieved by following the steps below. You can refer to whether Visual Studio 2019 has this setting.

Tools > Options > Debugging > General > Uncheck "Bring Visual Studio to the foreground when breaking in the debugger"

[image]

Hope it helps you